# Proper way to handle BLE Error Codes

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here is the list of error which i got while developing **BLE** App for **A&D UA-651BLE** model

```
onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=5 device=D0:5F:B8:03:79:70
onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=5 device=5C:31:3E:5E:E2:36
onClientConnectionState() - status=19 clientIf=5 device=5C:31:3E:5E:E2:36
```

As of now I'm handling this with `gatt.disconnect();` ,

**Description of above error codes :**

22 is 0x16 which means connection terminated by local host.

8 is 0x8 which means connection timeout.

19 is 0x13 which means connection terminate by peer user.

---

**How  to handle this in different way?**

1.Is there any way to handle this issue other than disconnecting **BluetoothGatt?** (Just curious to know)

2.Shall I show popup to user that your values are stored in BP device,On next successful connection vital device will push your values automatically?

---

**P.S:** If I see from developer's perspective,I know that this is BLE Stack exception,By if i see from user's perspective,they will think something wrong in android app,that is why it is not Showing my BP reading in android Screen.

Comment: 22 is caused by disconnect() and can be ignored.
the others indicate a disconection.  you might either inform the user things were disconnected, or reconnect.
where did you find these codes?  i can't find their documentaiton